# With "ImageIO.write()" API call I get NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, javax.imageio

With `ImageIO.write()` API call, I get `NullPointerException` when I pass a non-existent path like `"\\abc\abc.png"`. I pass the non-existent path purposely to test something but instead of getting `FileNotFoundException`, I get `NPE`.  Why is that?

`ImageIO.write()` API is supposed to throw `IOException` but don't why I get `NPE`.

I use exception message string to show it in a message box to user but in this case `NPE.getLocalizedMessage()` returns empty string and hence the popup is empty with just an icon on it.

Comment: Share the code where this exception occurs please

Comment: There is no ImageIO.write() method taking a String path as argument. Show us your code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Also, you could even show your `stacktrace`.

Comment: General tips.  1) Even if you can find a J2SE method that accepts a String to represent a file  path or URL, do not use it, instead use the overloaded variants that accept a `File` or `URL`.  2) If using a `File`, get it from a `JFileChooser`.  Easier for the user and more reliable. 3) `"\\abc\abc.png"` is not a valid file path on ***any*** OS, & it seems to me it would not compile.  Stop wasting your time (& more importantly ours) by typing 'something like' the code used.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I am not interested in wasting mine or anyone else's time.. Not my fault if you could not understand the question like Peter did. However, I found the reason/solution to my query. Thanks for being rude.

Comment: *"I am not interested in wasting mine or anyone else's time.."*  The proof is in the doing, rather than the saying.  Try to remember that in future.  Your question was shoddily researched & expressed, as suggested by the 2 *other* down votes it earned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He *is* right, though. For example, this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
 File out = new File("\\\\ABC\\abc.png");
 ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
}
```

gives

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ABC\abc.png (The network path was not found)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(FileImageOutputStream.java:69)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(FileImageOutputStreamSpi.java:55)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(ImageIO.java:419)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1530)
at javaapplication145.JavaApplication145.main(JavaApplication145.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1538)
at javaapplication145.JavaApplication145.main(JavaApplication145.java:24)
```

The reason is that `FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance` swallows the FileNotFoundException and then the NPE comes when `ImageIO.write` tries to close a stream that didn't open.

Why the exception is suppressed so brutally, I don't know. The code fragment is

```
try {
 return new FileImageOutputStream((File)output);
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 return null;
}
```

The only solution is to verify the path *before* attempting to use ImageIO.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to catch only NullPointerException? And let other exceptions go up the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason for NPE for issue mentioned in this thread. Peter Hull is absolutely right in saying

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);  File out = new File("\\\\ABC\\abc.png");  ImageIO.write(image, "png", out); }
```

This is exactly my code looks like. Thanks Peter for highlighting.

The reason for this issue is that new FileImageOutputStream() throws a FileNotFoundException but some Sun programmer went and caught the exception, printed the stack trace, and returned null. Which is why it's no longer possible to catch the FileNotFoundException - it's already printed. Shortly afterwards, the returned null value causes a NullPointerException, which is what it being thrown from the method I called. When printed the Stack Trace of the exception, I could see *FileNotFoundException* along with *NPE* for the reason mentioned above.

-Nayan