# when and how will ImageIO.write throw nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

In the

> ImageIO.write(RenderedImage,String,File)

method, ImageOutputStream is created through

> stream = **createImageOutputStream**(output);.

In the **createImageOutputStream** A runtime exception is caught and returns null from catch block.

```
try {
    iter = theRegistry.getServiceProviders(ImageOutputStreamSpi.class,true);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Can anyone help me understand:

1. What is the reason behind catching a runtime exception here?(unless it is a crappy coding)
2. On what condition, will the code throw illegal argument exception? (I dont see any reason for it to throw)

Please help.

Comment: if `ImageOutputStreamSpi.class` wasnt added here, then `getServiceProviders`  would throw. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/imageio/spi/IIORegistry.java#IIORegistry.0initialCategories

Comment: Why wouldn't it be added though? looks they are hardcoded inside a static block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a case of code that has evolved over time and no one cared to clean up, or it could be that the implementers of `ImageIO` relied on the contract of `ServiceRegistry`, rather than the implementation details of it. In the current implementation of `ImageIO` and `ServiceRegistry` I don't see how this could ever happen.

The only good thing I can see about it, is that you could now potentially change the implementation of `IIORegistry` or  `ServiceRegistry` to do lazy loading of categories for example, or perhaps flush out categories with no Service Providers (Spi) present. The contracts of the methods would not break, and the `ImageIO` class would still work as it does.

Now, back to the question in your question, the answer is it *should never* throw `NullPointerException`. *

If you really want to, you could get `stream` to be `null`, by de-registering the Spi for `File` (`FileImageOutputStreamSpi`). But even then, a well-behaved `ImageWriter` should throw an `IllegalStateException` indicating that the output has not been set, not a `NullPointerException` (of course, programming errors could cause NPEs in other places, but this is not normal flow).

**Update:**

*) As the OP himself pointed out in the linked answer, throwing of `NullPointerException` can indeed happen if you pass a `File` object pointing to a non-existing path. This happens because the `FileImageOutputStreamSpi` "swallows" the `IOException` caused by the `RandomAccessFile` constructor (it does print the stacktrace to standard out), and returns `null`. In my opinion, this breaks the contract in a more severe way than it would by just letting the `IOException` bubble up, or wrapping it in an `IllegalArgumentException` with the original exception as cause and some explanatory message. Consider filing a bug report, if it doesn't already exist one for this issue.

Comment: Yes. there is no reason of getting NPE. But people are getting this exception so I was wondering why. e.g here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153200/with-imageio-write-api-call-i-get-nullpointerexception?rq=1

Comment: @Hirak Weirdness... The contract (of `ImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(...)`) specifies that  `IOException` can only be thrown if the *cache file is needed but cannot be created*. So it's stupid, but kind of correct. I think it should either throw `IOException` or `IllegalArgumentException` in this case, rather than returning `null`, but obviously someone thought otherwise.

Comment: @Hirak Came to think of it, you could probably de-register the default `FileImageOutputStreamSpi` and replace it with your own that has the desired behavior (i.e. throws the exception as suggested above, instead of returning `null`).

Comment: we could do that...I will try. So far I used the ImageIO.write which accepts a fileinputstream instead of file. that did it for me.